# Почему std::optional::operator= не содержит & квалификатора?

Tags: c++, дизайн-языка

Почему оператор присваивания для `std::optional` не содержит `&` квалификатора для предотвращения присваиваний rvalue-ссылкам https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D?

```
constexpr optional& operator=( const optional& other ) /* no & here */;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества что именно непонятно?

Comment: Дух = это бот, за ним обычно скрывается какой то пользователь, который решил, что Ваш вопрос для него не понятен (например, потому что проверящий не знает с++). Есть несколько активных проверяющих, которые регулярно отмечают вопрос как непонятен.

Comment: то есть, вы хотите избежать что то вида `std::variant<int> get() {
    return std::variant<int>{1};
}

int main() {
    get() = 1;
}`?

Comment: @KoVadim да, вот примеры http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2819.html#Motivation, для `std::optional` можно было поставить, т.к. нет проблем с обратной совместимостью; значит, есть другие причины, почему не поставили

Comment: Я думаю, тут две причины. Страуструп и команда очень не любят частичных решений, особенно тех, которые выбиваются с общей канвы. Во вторых, этот тип делался как замена (адаптация) типа с boost. И что бы не сломать код, иногда так делают